# Increase in temporary tablespace while import

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, import, impdp

When i am importing some tables in my database, the temporary tablespace is getting full. This never happened earlier for other tables.

Please help me know why this is happening and any solution for it.

ParFile:

```
ParFile:
Directory=IMPDIR
DUMPFILE=expdp.dump
TABLE=scott.table1,scott.table2,scott.table2,scott.table3,scott.table4
TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=append
CONTENT=DATA_ONLY
REMAP_SCHEMA=scott:hr
REMAP_TABLESPACE=users:testtbs
PARALLEL=10
LOGFILE=impdp.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The size needed in a temporary tablespace depends on the data volume manipulated, but including potentially other actions also requiring temporary space. What you should be doing is this : monitor temporary tablespace usage, (temporarily) expand the temporary tablespace.

Maybe, you need to recreate your temp tablespace. That is, if there is corruption of some kind. One way - but not the only one - is stopping the database, rename the file(s) of the temporary tablespace, tail the alert.log, and startup the database. Obviously, don't do without backup, and don't test this on production.